# IBM Watson Assistant: How to set a context variable from option response?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I couldn't figure out a problem with IBM Watson Assistant. I've chosen to use an **Option** type as response. That way, I can see a list on my chatbot where each item is clickable and has an associated value.

When a user clicks one of the options, the associated user input value is sent to the assistant. How can I give this value to a context variable? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible for [option responses](https://github.com/data-henrik/chatbot-talks/blob/2020letsmake/INSTRUCTIONS.md) and is the typical use case. I have demonstrated that in a [simple chatbot](https://github.com/data-henrik/chatbot-talks/blob/2020letsmake/INSTRUCTIONS.md) I use in some of my talks.

I use different language code as options. Users can click on them and the result is saved in the variable **langcode**. Because users could have already specified what I would ask for, I check for it and save it.

[image: list labels and options]

The simple bot has more uses of options and the full skill is available in case you want to see all the details.

Comment: Thanks, I have already thought about this solution but I would not like to use an entity because the development should be more complex and the "list label" dynamic. I thought there was a way to give a value to  $ langcode after the user clicked on a choice, before moving on the another node.

Comment: The entity is only an example. You can check for anything you want. Remember that not all clients can render options and not all users click on the option, but enter a response. You need to be able to react to any input